# get values of multiselect dropdown in order of selection

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am using multiselect dropdown with checkboxes. I need the value of the selected items in the order of selection.

```
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="One">One</option>
    <option value="Two">Two</option>
    <option value="Three">Three</option>
    <option value="Four">Four</option>
</select>
```

Suppose I select Three, One, Two.(in this order)

```
var values=$('#dropdown').val();
```

Using this values=[One,Two,Three], the order in which they are in the list. But I want values=[Three,One,Two], the order in which I selected.

How can that be done?

Comment: and if you select the first and then the last with shift, so select everything?

Comment: yes, thats possible